# ImageDataGenerator flow_from_directory rounds up the image

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

i am trying to implement the u-net in tensorflow and i need a way to load a weight map from a folder. I modified an ImageDataGenerator to suit my needs , namely this code.

```
border_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**aug_dict)
```

with aug_dict being parameters for augmentation that i set to 0. specifically:

```
data_gen_args = dict(rotation_range=0,
                width_shift_range=0,
                height_shift_range=0,
                shear_range=0,
                zoom_range=0,
                horizontal_flip=False,
                fill_mode='wrap'
                )


border_generator = border_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_path,
    classes = [border_folder],
    class_mode = None,
    color_mode = "grayscale",
    target_size = target_size,
    batch_size = batch_size,
    save_to_dir = save_to_dir,
    save_prefix  = image_save_prefix,
    seed = seed)
```

yet, when i try to load the image it is weirdly rounded up. Specifically, the blobs that should be there dissapear and only the very high weights of the close borders remain.

Specifically, the image should look like this:
[image]

but ends up looking like this[image]

A potential example of image would be found here
https://dropmefiles.com/Xf4lB

thank you for your help

Comment: What is in `aug_dict `

Comment: augmentation parameters which i set to 0 for this test. Specifically
data_gen_args = dict(rotation_range=0,
                    width_shift_range=0,
                    height_shift_range=0,
                    shear_range=0,
                    zoom_range=0,
                    horizontal_flip=False,
                    fill_mode='wrap'
                    )

which is what is passed for this

Comment: Do you have some example data?

Comment: certainly.
i ll edit the original answer for this

Comment: Yes, the image is being resized (the parameter target_size), so interpolation is needed, there is a interpolation parameter that you can control to set which interpolation algorithm is used, none of this is weird.

Comment: That might be the case. Is there any method/way that i can resize the image without losing the blobs?

Answer (score 0):

THANK YOU ALL.
Indeed it was the resizing as @Dr. Snoopy said.
The quick and dirty fix was to multiply the image by a high value before resizing.